# Appending to text files with "sed" in Linux

Tags: regex, linux, sed, expression, linux-mint

I have a text file containing phone numbers. I have to append and area code "456-" to the phone numbers in the file with sed, then append the line to another text file without erasing any of it's contents.

What's a good command for this? I'm using Linux Mint. My regex is:

```
grep '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' file.txt
```

Comment: can you post some sample data of `file.txt`.

Comment: Word word word 123-4567 word word.

Comment: No, don't post a comment describing your input - update your question to show some actual sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Try the command below:

```
sed -e 's/[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{4\}/456-&/g' file.txt >> another_file.txt
```

Comment: Worked very well. Thanks

Comment: You should do a test for space before and after number, so string like this would not be changed `123-4567-1234`